# how can i handle this error : Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database, laravel-6

I'm producing an online school platform and in part of it student can see it's classes with their informations..but the related function return this error : Undefined offset: 0 (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\OnlineSchool\resources\views\admin\student\ClassReport.blade.php)

there are some relations between models
My Models:

USER(students and teachers) ، LEVEL(level of classes) ، Classroom.

=> there is a many to many relation between student and classroom (pivot table)

please save me from this stupid error
user:

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','image','level','code_meli',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

   public function classroom(){
        return $this->hasMany  (classroom::class);
    }

    public function ClassRoomStudent(){
        return $this->belongsToMany (classroom::class ,'classroom_user','user_id','classroom_id');
    }
}
```

classroom:

```
class classroom extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'teacher_id', 'level_id','day','time','price',
    ];

    public function Student(){
        return $this->belongsToMany (user::class ,'classroom_user','classroom_id','user_id');
    }

    public function level(){
        return $this->belongsTo (level::class );
    }
    public function teacher(){
        return $this->belongsTo (user::class );
    }

}
```

level :

```
class level extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
    ];

    public function classroom(){
        return $this->hasMany (classroom::class);
    }
    public function exam(){
        return $this->hasMany (exam::class);
    }
}
```

and my function in controller:

```
public function MyClasses(){
    $student_id=auth ()->user ()->id;
    $classrooms=classroom::with ('level','teacher','factor')->wherehas('student',function ($q) use($student_id){
        $q->where('id',$student_id);
    })->get();
     
    return view ('admin.student.ClassReport',compact ('classrooms','student_id'));
}
```

at the end .. my blade:

```
 @foreach($classrooms as $class)
                    <tr>

                        <td>{{$i++}}</td>
                        <td>{{$class->title}}</td>
                        <td>{{$class->teacher[0]->name}}</td>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Why the `$class->teacher[0]->name` and not `$class->teacher->name`?

Comment: `public function teacher()` returns a single `User` instance, or `null`; it is not an array/Collection, so you cannot use `[0]` (array index), nor do you need to. `$class->teacher->name ?? 'None'` will output the name of the Teacher, or `None` if the class doesn't have one.

Comment: Also, _please_ fix your coding standards; don't add unnecessary spacing, like `auth ()->user ()->id`, should be `auth()->user()->id`, and model names are `StudlyCase`, `User`, `Level`, `Classroom`, etc, and be consistent; `public function classroom()` and `public function ClassRoomStudent()` use wildly different cases... Should be `public function classroom()` and `public function classroomStudent()`

Comment: i did it but i still get this error @Qirel

Answer (score 0):

The Classroom belongs to only one teacher, no need to use de zero index, just type $class->teacher->name